# Neo4j REST API Java binding Uniqueness deprecated

Tags: java, api, rest, neo4j, deprecated

I want to use Uniqueness for my Traversal.

Based on [this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_uniqueness), I'm using the following code :

```
GraphDatabaseService database = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
TraversalDescription td = database.traversalDescription().uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);
```

This code gave me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Only values of class org.neo4j.kernel.Uniqueness are supported
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal.RestTraversal.restify(RestTraversal.java:63)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal.RestTraversal.uniqueness(RestTraversal.java:54)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal.RestTraversal.uniqueness(RestTraversal.java:50)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.traversal.RestTraversal.uniqueness(RestTraversal.java:37)
```

I already had to change the `Traversal.description()` to `database.traversalDescription()` because of deprecated but now I face the same problem for Uniqueness. In my example I used org.neo4j.graphdb.traversal.Uniquess because org.neo4j.kernel.Uniqueness is deprecated...
When using the package mentionned by the error I have a `NullPointerException` during the `traverse()` method, with no stack trace.

I'm using :

- REST API : neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.0-M06.jar
- Neo4j : neo4j-desktop-2.0.0.jar

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There have been API changes in Neo4j 2.0 which are not in neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.0-M06

If you pull the latest neo4j-rest-graphdb github repo and build it locally it should work against: neo4j-rest-graphdb-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I'm looking at this repo https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/releases but I already pulled the latest version.
If I look into the source code of the dependency, the class Uniqueness is the same (with deprecated)